# Oracle SQL join on column with multiple Line feed (chr(10)) seperated values

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Below are the sample tables I have to join.

```
SQL> select 'CH1' chapter , 'HELLO'||chr(10)||'WORLD' output from dual union
  2  select 'CH2' chapter , 'HELLO'||chr(10)||'GALAXY' output from dual union
  3  select 'CH3' chapter , 'HELLO'||chr(10)||'UNIVERSE'  output from dual;

CHAPTER         OUTPUT
--------------- --------------
CH1             HELLO
                WORLD

CH2             HELLO
                GALAXY

CH3             HELLO
                UNIVERSE
```

and

```
SQL> select 'WORLD' output, 'PG1' Page from dual union
  2  select 'GALAXY' output, 'PG2' Page from dual union
  3  select 'UNIVERSE' output, 'PG3' Page from dual;

    OUTPUT   PAGE
-------- ------------
GALAXY   PG2
UNIVERSE PG3
WORLD    PG1
```

The OUTPUT column in the first table has multiple values seperated with chr(10) which I want to join with the OUTPUT column of second table so that the output looks like following:

```
CHAPTER         OUTPUT          PAGE
--------------- --------------  ----------------
CH1             HELLO               P1
                WORLD

CH2             HELLO               P2
                GALAXY

CH3             HELLO               P3
                UNIVERSE
```

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Don't store lists of things in a single column.  Use a junction table instead.

Comment: It doesn't look like the OP is storing lists of things. This looks more like assembling an index for a book; the single column contains one thing per row, a full chapter of text.

Comment: What if you get a partial match? Should `HELL` match `HELLO`?

Comment: @dnoeth - VERY GOOD POINT!  OP - please think abut this question and let us know what the requirement should be. It is possible that in the end, the solution will have to use regular expressions. This is not difficult, but the requirement must be very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select chapter, c.output, page
from   table_chapters c join table_pages p
   on c.output like '%' || p.output || '%'
order by chapter, page
```

The join condition matches if the output in the "pages" table is an exact substring of the output in the "chapters" table. I assume this is what you need.

If you need the output sorted as I have shown, care must be taken because in lexicographic sorting P10 is before P3. Best if page numbers are in NUMBER format, not string format. Same with chapters.

Comment: Thank you!! seems like '%'||p.output||'%" is what works in Oracle.

Comment: I saw Gordon's edit, too... I am losing my mind. I only work in Oracle and I only use || for concatenation, did I really put & in my answer? Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

If the join needs to be done always on the second row of the string, you can use:

```
SQL> select chapter, a.output, page
  2  from test_a A
  3       inner join test_B B
  4         on ( substr(a.output, instr(a.output, chr(10))+1, length(a.output)) = B.output)
  5  order by chapter;

CHA OUTPUT         PAG
--- -------------- ---
CH1 HELLO          PG1
    WORLD

CH2 HELLO          PG2
    GALAXY

CH3 HELLO          PG3
    UNIVERSE
```

Comment: The third argument to substr shows the length of the substring to be extracted, not the position of the last character. Also, by default (if the third argument is missing) substr will read through the end of the input string, so you can safely leave it out altogether (instead of replacing what you have with an even longer expression).

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.*, B.PAGE from
(select 'CH1' chapter , 'HELLO'||chr(10)||'WORLD' output from dual union
select 'CH2' chapter , 'HELLO'||chr(10)||'GALAXY' output from dual union
select 'CH3' chapter , 'HELLO'||chr(10)||'UNIVERSE'  output from dual ) A
JOIN
(select 'WORLD' output, 'PG1' Page from dual union
select 'GALAXY' output, 'PG2' Page from dual union
select 'UNIVERSE' output, 'PG3' Page from dual) B
on a.output like '%'||b.output||'%';

CHAPTER         OUTPUT          PAGE
--------------- --------------  ----------------
CH1             HELLO               P1
                WORLD

CH2             HELLO               P2
                GALAXY

CH3             HELLO               P3
                UNIVERSE
```

Comment: ?  I think this is EXACTLY the solution I offered, what is different here?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT 
    A.chapter, 
    A.output, 
    B.Page
FROM
    (select 'CH1' chapter , 'HELLO'||chr(10)||'WORLD' output from dual union
     select 'CH2' chapter , 'HELLO'||chr(10)||'GALAXY' output from dual union
     select 'CH3' chapter , 'HELLO'||chr(10)||'UNIVERSE'  output from dual) A,
    (select 'WORLD' output, 'PG1' Page from dual union
     select 'GALAXY' output, 'PG2' Page from dual union
     select 'UNIVERSE' output, 'PG3' Page from dual) B
WHERE
    A.output LIKE '%'||B.output
ORDER BY A.chapter;
```

sample output

```
SQL> SELECT
  2     A.chapter,
  3     A.output,
  4     B.Page
  5  FROM
  6     (select 'CH1' chapter , 'HELLO'||chr(10)||'WORLD' output from dual union
  7      select 'CH2' chapter , 'HELLO'||chr(10)||'GALAXY' output from dual union
  8      select 'CH3' chapter , 'HELLO'||chr(10)||'UNIVERSE'  output from dual) A,
  9     (select 'WORLD' output, 'PG1' Page from dual union
 10      select 'GALAXY' output, 'PG2' Page from dual union
 11      select 'UNIVERSE' output, 'PG3' Page from dual) B
 12  WHERE
 13     A.output LIKE '%'||B.output
 14  ORDER BY A.chapter;

CHA OUTPUT         PAG
--- -------------- ---
CH1 HELLO          PG1
    WORLD

CH2 HELLO          PG2
    GALAXY

CH3 HELLO          PG3
    UNIVERSE
```